# How to verify if a user is using or not using an app

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to distinguish on the server side if a userid is using an app. I can use `token_for_business` and it will return an error, but that seams not the right way, do you know how?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Is this is your own app?  If so you could define a custom user-agent string, and then check for that server side.

Comment: Yes, it is my own - I will have to look into what a user-agent string is ;-)

Comment: Ok, thanks - but what would you pass on in the header "User-Agent":"?" to get the information regarding using the app or not?

Comment: A user-agent string identifies the browser (or in your case, the app!) that a user is accessing your site with. It gets passed to your server in the HTTP header.
A user with Chrome browser will have a user-agent string similar to: _Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36._
Someone on Internet Explorer will look like this:
_Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; AS; rv:11.0) like Gecko_

Your app's user-agent could be something like _ChrisGApp/1.0_

Comment: You can define your own user-agent any way you like. It is probably a good idea to include some version information, so if you release different version of your app that behave in different ways you know what version of an app a user is using.  You can get a list of some user-agents [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php)